# Non physical hardware switch

Tags: laptop, battery, power

My laptop comes equipped with a hardware switch on its backside that connects/disconnects the battery. When I am connected to AC for example, I can thus avoid overcharging the battery.

Yesterday something mind-boggling (to me at least) happened. I tried to load up a Ubuntu live system and during the boot up it crashed really really hard (I found out by now that I can avoid this crash by turning off my wireless antenna). I don't think I have ever seen a crash like this. The screen froze with an error message, all keys were completely unresponsive, even the power key did not do anything anymore. All right, I thought, let's unplug the AC connector and disconnect the battery. Guess what happened: nothing. To my utter surprise the laptop just kept running in fact I was so surprised by this, that I even filmed it. Then I thought, ok the switch is probably broken. Well, it isn't. After the battery had died, I cold boot up Windows like before, everything works normally and the hardware switch still disconnects the battery.

How can this be true? How does such a switch work? Is it software controlled? I can't imagine that, because it also works when the laptop is shut down.

Comment: Most likely your switch does not disconnect the battery, it only disables charging from the AC source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Majority of the modern battery-powered gadgetry (laptops, cell phones, pads, pods, etc) aren't entirely powered down, as long as there's some charge left in the battery.  Some kind of controller always remains powered from the battery.  One of its responsibilities is to respond to user pressing the on/off button and to control the power to the main processor and other payload.  It may have other responsibilities too.  Selecting the power source may be one of them.

This standby controller is optimized such that is consumes only a small amount of power and doesn't discharge the battery appreciably.  The sophistication of these controllers vary from simple digital logic to microcontrollers with their own firmware.

Comment: Most, if not all, modern ACPI laptops have what is called an "Embedded Controller" (EC).  EC's do have firmware and sometimes it will be updated along with a BIOS update.